# Template metaprogramming example doesn't make sense

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming

I am looking at an example of loop unrolling via template metaprogramming:

```
template<int i, typename FuncType>
class Loop
{
    public:
        static inline void Do(FuncType func) {
            Loop<i-1, FuncType>::Do(func);
            func(i);
        }
};

template<typename FuncType>
class Loop<-1, FuncType>
{
    public:
        static inline void Do(FuncType func) { }
};


void DoWork(int i) { cout << “DoWork(“ << i << “)” << endl; }
int main()
{
    Loop<3, decltype(DoWork)>::Do(DoWork);
}
```

I don't understand why the first template class doesn't have any template arguments on the same line as `Class Loop`, but the template class to handle when the loop finished does:

`class Loop<-1, FuncType>`

I would have expected both to have identical declarations, except the second **partial specialization** with the -1 case.

Comment: The second thing is called a *partial specialization*. It is used instead of the *primary template* (the first thing) whenever the first template argument is `-1`.

Comment: Ok so why did the partial specialization need to include FuncType on the same line as Class Loop, couldnt it have just said class Loop<-1> because the primary template doesn't even have anything on the same line as class Loop?

Comment: The `<..>` after `Loop` specifies when the partial specialization shall be used instead of the primary template. Since the primary template is always the fallback / default case, it does not need one.

Comment: Ok so i think im right in saying that because the -1 specialisation is specified, the rest of the "template" has to be specified, hence <-1, FuncType>? You cant have a specialisation showing only have the parameters basically?

Comment: The class template is still `template<int, typename> class Loop;` It has two template parameters. The specialization must define for which cases it shall apply, it does so by providing some kind of pattern for each template argument to be checked against. In this case, the first template argument supplied to `Loop` is compared to `-1`, and the second one can be any type (for the specialization to match). There's no terse notation where you could leave out some parameters which are not restricted.

Comment: [Here's an example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43560c686799c7ab) of a partial specialization with more template parameters than the primary template.

Comment: Ah ok so it is just the class name which is used to associate all the templates together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the difference in syntax is that the first `template` statement declares a general template, whereas the second declares a [partial specialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization) of this template. The arguments

```
<-1, FuncType>
```

following the class name describe the conditions under which this specialization should be used - in this case when the first argument is `-1`.